# Why is my Joomla website giving this error? Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: joomla1.5

My website is intermittently giving me the following error:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 80 bytes) in /home//public_html/libraries/joomla/database/database/mysqli.php on line 478

Upon researching I found that there are lots of modules / extensions that could probably cause

It is a shared hosting package and following are the PHP specifications (taken from Joomla Admin):

- PHP Version 5.2.17
- memory_limit  512M (local)    64M (Master Value - not sure what that means)

This problem is recurring and I am unable to solve it even after I have disabled all plugins which we are using. I am not sure what is to be done. Will upgrading to a better server with more PHP memory_limit help?

Link to my website:

bit.ly/RAKDtx

Comment: A huge memory limit is a poor substitute for good coding. Have you recently installed any particular component on your site that you suspect might be hogging on memory? Which particular page of your site is throwing this error? Or does this reoccur intermittently on all pages?

Comment: The part that looks weird to me is that your Admin says the limit is 512 MB, but the error says it has used up all *128* MB allowed. Some file/plugin must be changing that limit behind your back - run a search for `'memory_limit'` and see if anything looks out of place.

Comment: Also, not only plugins and modules can cause this, templates too can cause problems.

Comment: Hi vermisimilitude,

Honestly, this is occuring across the website and we fail to understand the problem.

My configuration.php file was not writable. I just made it writable. It seems to have solved the problem. But I am still not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in in configuration.php:

```
ini_set ('memory_limit', '128M ');
```

OR put this in .htaccess file:

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
```

And, maybe you can change that value to 256 if 128 dont work. Good luck.

And about Master value:

> The value shown in the “Local” column is the memory limit you are working with.  If no Local value is set, then the Master value is your memory limit.

Comment: We tried putting tweaking the with ini_set  and php_value memory_limit but that does not help as we are on  a shared server and its limited to 64 MB. I heard that this could be because of a "large" database that is causing mysqli to time out. I am not a php programmer and work with plugins / extensions  that work for my client. Even when I have disabled all of them, this error persists - so that cause is ruled out.

Comment: We have the following modules functional on this Joomla site i.e.:

- Forum (ninjaboard)
- Video player that pulls videos from YouTube (webplayer HD)
- 2 Audio players which has a large number of mp3 files being played from the server itself (saudioplayer and mp3browser)
- another Events module

(Rest of the website is just static pages)

I also checked if this is caused because of too many visitors (as a result more DB queries) being generated on the website (since it is happening intermittently) and found that overall the mean usage of bandwidth of my website is about 3 GB per month.

Comment: For those who can help me out, I just disabled all plugins to this Joomla website and I am pretty sure now that they were not hogging on my memory. 

Even did a database repair to make sure there aren't any missing tables (did this repair through cPanel).

Now the question is how to resolve this issue which may be caused by something else. Will updating Joomla really solve the issue and if it is a Joomla core files problem, how do I go about solving it?

Comment: My configuration.php file was not writable. I just made it writable. It seems to have solved the problem. But I am still not sure. Will re-enable modules to see if that again causes the problems. The problem persisted even  when they were disabled so hopefully this is over.

Comment: Upon meticulously enabling and disabling I found "JV counter" was the problem. Incidentally, someone had also commented on the Joomla directory that "JV counter" causes php_memory limit issues. Now, that makes me pretty confident that that is the culprit! My website seems to work fine now. Appreciate everyone posting their tips to help me out. Highly appreciate it. In case the error persists, I will surely post back again here...

Comment: Glad you found the solution. As i can see that plugin saves large amount of data in database (info of every visitor), and then calls that data and sort them by time of visit. That could be very memory expensive, especially on sites withbig number of visitors.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the memory limit recurring issue, so I changed twice, from 64 to 128 then to 256 mo, (paying more to my provider), a coupla months later the problem was back. The whole site was desperatly slow, too.
I disabled JV counter, and everything's back, up and running again!
Some bad coding to rewrite, buddies!